# Performance counter monitoring in applications and for SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql, monitoring

We are looking for a performance counter monitoring tool, like Perfmon. But this tool should in addition save the data automatically in a database and should have nice reporting abilities. If possible it should be even Web based and for free.

We want to use it for benchmarking our distributed .NET application and some connected SQL servers. So maybe we need next to performance counters also to execute SQL statements to get some numbers back.

At the moment we are not sure if we should use an agent based or an agent-less benchmarking / monitoring solution.

We are also seriously thinking about developing our own solution, but I think something like this must already exist.

Thanks for your help!
Best regards
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

On the SQL Server side, two of my favorite monitoring tools are:

- [Idera's SQL diagnostic manager](http://www.idera.com/Products/SQL-Server/SQL-diagnostic-manager/)
- [Confio's Ignite for SQL Server](http://www.confio.com/English/Products/Ignite_for_SQL_Server.php)

Answer (score 1):

For historical data we have been using SQLH2 with good success and ports easyly to SQL reports and it's free. For realtime activity try DIAB from DIABSqlSoftware.com it handles all the major performance counters and is very inexpensive. It also monitors scheduled jobs, replication, backups, diskspace and a load of other features.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Enterprise Library Application Logging Block, it supports logging to a Database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647183.aspx

Also here is a good article on how it can be implemented to utilize performance tracing in your applications.

http://www.michaelhamrah.com/blog/2010/02/performance-tracing-for-your-applications-via-enterprise-library/

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server I would suggest looking at DMVs to Identify Missing Indexes, CPU issues, IO Issues.

DMVs and values to check are listed in article - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966401.aspx

Ready to Use Queries for DMVs you can download from link  - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimmymay/archive/2008/10/30/drum-roll-please-the-debut-of-the-sql-dmv-all-stars-dream-team.aspx